# How to install the latest version of Eclipse Classic on Ubuntu 12.04 using the terminal?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, installation, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

Please how to install the latest Eclipse Classic (4.2) on Ubuntu 12.04 using the terminal? if you can direct me step-by-step, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this blog post [here](http://blog.brunobraga.net/eclipse-42-in-ubuntu-1204), for step-by-step instructions.

The process is documented step-by-step and in the comments the author has included a script -

```
#!/bin/sh

ECLIPSE=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse

inject_update_site(){
if [ ! -e "$1" ] ; then
echo "W: Cannot find $1" 2>&1
return 1
fi
cat - >>"$1" <<EOF
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/enabled=true
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/isSystem=false
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/nickname=Indigo Update Site
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/uri=http\://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
EOF

}

if [ ! -d ~/.eclipse/ ] ; then
$ECLIPSE -clean -initialize || exit $?
artifact=$(find ~/.eclipse \
-regex .*/profileRegistry/.*/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs)
metadata=$(find ~/.eclipse \
-regex .*/profileRegistry/.*/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs)
if [ -z "$artifact" ] || [ -z "$metadata" ]; then
echo "W: Cannot inject update-sites, cannot find the correct config." 2>&1
else
( inject_update_site "$artifact" && \
inject_update_site "$metadata" && \
echo "I: Injected update sites" ) || echo "W: Could not inject update sites." 2>&1
fi
fi

exec $ECLIPSE "$@"
```

which works.

Comment: 11: /tmp/eclipse.sh: Syntax error: newline unexpected

Comment: @jameshfisher: make sure you use Unix, not DOS line endings

Answer (score 20):

**Step 1 »** Install java JDK or JRE

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

**Step 2 »** Download latest copy from here
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux

**Step 3 »** Move the downloaded package to /opt directory

```
sudo mv eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz /opt
```

**Step 4 »** Extract the package

```
sudo tar -xvf /opt/eclipse-SDK-4.2.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz -C /opt
```

**Step 5 »** Create a new desktop file ***eclipse.desktop*** in **/usr/share/applications/** and add the below lines .

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
```

**Step 6 »** Simply drag this **eclipse.desktop** file to the launcher.

Check this link : [install eclipse in ubuntu 12.04](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-eclipse-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to cd to the /opt folder before executing the tar command.  If you don't then the tar command will create the eclipse directory in whatever your current directory is.

Answer (score 0):

After installing java JDK or JRE run the following command and it'll install eclipse for you,

sudo apt-get install eclipse