# How to install eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am facing problem while installing tar `zxf eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz`

this `eclipse` file in `Ubuntu`. Please tell me how to unzip this file.

To unzip I used following commands

```
   1. $ gunzip file.gz  
   2. $ gunzip < file.tar.gz | tar xvf -
   3. $ gunzip < file.tgz | tar xvf -
```

Comment: tar -zxvf eclipse-cpp-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz giving any problem?

Comment: Yes I downloaded Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers and it was asking for jvm then I installed jvm but in terminal it is showing  bash :no such directorty .

Pls tell me , if i install eclipse cdt . how can i run it in terminal? If i need JVM environment,which is suitable for ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10. 



Thanks in advance

Comment: So do you have java installed? Eclipse can't run without java.

Comment: yes I have already installed java but still i am getting the same problem

Comment: I would be better if you can post the complete error.

Answer (score 1):

tar -xzf tar-file-name.tar.gz /path/to/location

or use 7Zip tool. right click and extract.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
#!/bin/sh

ECLIPSE=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse

inject_update_site(){
if [ ! -e "$1" ] ; then
echo "W: Cannot find $1" 2>&1
return 1
fi
cat - >>"$1" <<eof>
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/enabled=true
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/isSystem=false
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/nickname=Indigo Update Site
repositories/http\:__download.eclipse.org_releases_indigo/uri=http\://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/
EOF

}

if [ ! -d ~/.eclipse/ ] ; then
$ECLIPSE -clean -initialize || exit $?
artifact=$(find ~/.eclipse \
-regex .*/profileRegistry/.*/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs)
metadata=$(find ~/.eclipse \
-regex .*/profileRegistry/.*/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs)
if [ -z "$artifact" ] || [ -z "$metadata" ]; then
echo "W: Cannot inject update-sites, cannot find the correct config." 2>&1
else
( inject_update_site "$artifact" && \
inject_update_site "$metadata" && \
echo "I: Injected update sites" ) || echo "W: Could not inject update sites." 2>&1
fi
fi

exec $ECLIPSE "$@"
```

reference to 
[How to install the latest version of Eclipse Classic on Ubuntu 12.04 using the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003815/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-eclipse-classic-on-ubuntu-12-04-using-the-t)

Answer (score 0):

```
tar xzf xxxx.tar.gz
tar xjf xxxx.tar.bz2
```